# Bind (Include = ...) Parameter Not binding Model to Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm attempting to bind a model to an ActionResult and it's coming in as null. So it knows the model to place in but all values are null.

My ActionResult is:

```
public ActionResult Complete([Bind(Include = "ToDoId,Complete")] ViewModels.ToDo @todo)
        {
            using (var db = new KnightOwlContext())
            {
                DashboardHelper dashboardHelper = new DashboardHelper(db);

                dashboardHelper.CompleteToDo(todo.ToDoId, todo.Complete);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

And my button to trigger it is on a partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<KnightOwlCRM.ViewModels.ToDo>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <h5>To-Do</h5>
            <div class="ibox-tools">
                <a class="collapse-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="close-link">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">

            <p class="small"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i> Drag tasks to re-order them</p>

            <ul class="sortable-list connectList agile-list ui-sortable">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <li class="@item.Priority">
                        @item.Text
                        <div class="agile-detail">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Done", "Complete", "Home", new { id = item.ToDoId }, new { @class = "pull-right btn btn-xs btn-primary" })
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @item.Date
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that updates a record in a DB using Entity Framework in an referenced project:

```
public void CompleteToDo(int toDoId, bool complete)
        {
            var original = Db.ToDoes.Find(toDoId);

            if (original != null)
            {
                original.Complete = true;
                Db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Basically my endgame is to press abutton and update a record in the DB from False to True.

Comment: Firstly, updating a record should never be a GET method (us a form and POST the values). But as per you last question, you not passing values for the model, which contains a property named `ToDoId`, not a property named `id` which is what your link passes. In anycase, a GET method should not contain a parameter which is a model

Comment: Simply use `@using(Html.BeginForm("Complete", "Home", new { id = item.ToDoId }) { <input type="submit" value="Done" /> }` and change the method to `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Complete(int id)` (and use `dashboardHelper.CompleteToDo(id, true);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send these 2 parameter values with form data with matching keys. One way to do that is to keep it inside a form and submit it using http post method (because your method tries to update data. Any action method which updates data should be HttpPost action method).

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class="@item.Priority">@item.Text             
        <form action="@Url.Action("Complete","Home")" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="ToDoId" value="@item.ToDoId" />
           <input type="hidden" name="Complete" value="true" />
           <input type="submit" value="Done" />
        </form>
         <span>@item.Date</span>
       </div>
    </li>
}
```

I hard coded the value of the hidden input for the `Complete` field to `true` because i do not know what value to use there(*You did not provide that information in the question*). Replace it with the real value as needed. **But remember, user can update these values using browser dev tools**. So consider setting the values in server as needed.

Comment: "But remember, user can update these values using browser dev tools. So consider setting the values in server as needed." - How would I do this?

Comment: If it is always going to be true, pass `true` when you call your method in your action method like `dashboardHelper.CompleteToDo(todo.ToDoId, true)`

Comment: Thanks - And I take it if I add a button in that form then thats when the user will click that will trigger the action?

Comment: Yes ! Sorry i missed that part. Updated the answer now.